# Class-objects, singleton classes

Tags: ruby, oop, metaprogramming

I play with metaprogramming in ruby and I have a question. I have a class:

```
class Klass
  class << self
    @x = "yeah"
  end
end
b = Klass.new
a = class << Klass; self; end
a.instance_eval "@x"           #=> yeah
Klass.instance_eval "@x"       #=> nil
```

Why? In variable `a` I have a singleton class, right? And `Klass.instance_eval` exec in context of a singleton class:

```
Klass.instance_eval "def yeah; puts 10; end"
Klass.yeah                     #=> 10
```

Also, `Klass` in interpreter points to context of class, yes? And `a` points to context of a singleton class?
And which indicates `a.class_eval` and `a.instance_eval`? I do:

```
a.instance_eval "def pops; puts 0; end"
a.class_eval "def popsx; puts 1; end"
a.pops                         #=> 0
a.popsx                        # FAIL
Klass.pops                     # FAIL
Klass.popsx                    #=> 1
b.pops; b.popsx                # DOUBLE FAIL
```

and I do not understand this. Thanks!

Comment: Edited the question by replacing "eigenclass" by the official term "singleton class".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, while it seems like *eigentclass* is used by some people *singleton class* is more common term. Singleton class contains object-specific behavior for an object in Ruby. You can't create other instances of that class except the original object this singleton class belongs to.

Speaking about defining of methods inside different types of eval [this article](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2009/01/09/fun-with-rubys-instance_eval-and-class_eval/) introduces nice rule for methods defined in `instance_eval` and `class_eval`:

> ```
> Use ClassName.instance_eval to define class methods.
> Use ClassName.class_eval to define instance methods.
> ```

That pretty much describes the situation.

*There was a huge write-up about classes that are instances of Class class, their singleton classes that are subclasses of Class class and some other crazy stuff (not that much related to the problem). But as your question can be easily applied to regular objects and their classes (and it makes things much easier to explain), I decided to remove that all (though, you can still see that stuff in revisions history of the answer).*

Let's look at regular class and instance of that class and see how that all works:

```
class A; end
a = A.new
```

Method definitions inside different types of eval:

```
# define instance method inside class context
A.class_eval { def bar; 'bar'; end }
puts a.bar     # => bar
puts A.new.bar # => bar

# class_eval is equivalent to re-opening the class
class A
  def bar2; 'bar2'; end
end
puts a.bar2     # => bar2
puts A.new.bar2 # => bar2
```

Defining object-specific methods:

```
# define object-specific method in the context of object itself
a.instance_eval { def foo; 'foo'; end }
puts a.foo # => foo

# method definition inside instance_eval is equivalent to this
def a.foo2; 'foo2'; end
puts a.foo2 # => foo2

# no foo method here
# puts A.new.foo # => undefined method `foo' for #<A:0x8b35b20>
```

Let's now look at singleton class of object `a`:

```
# singleton class of a is subclass of A
p (class << a; self; end).ancestors
# => [A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

# define instance method inside a's singleton class context
class << a
  def foobar; 'foobar'; end;
end
puts a.foobar # => foobar

# as expected foobar is not available for other instances of class A
# because it's instance method of a's singleton class and a is the only
# instance of that class
# puts A.new.foobar # => undefined method `foobar' for #<A:0x8b35b20>

# same for equivalent class_eval version
(class << a; self; end).class_eval do
  def foobar2; 'foobar2'; end;
end
puts a.foobar2 # => foobar2

# no foobar2 here as well
# puts A.new.foobar2 # => undefined method `foobar2' for #<A:0x8b35b20>
```

Now let's look at instance variables:

```
# define instance variable for object a
a.instance_eval { @x = 1 }

# we can access that @x using same instance_eval
puts a.instance_eval { @x } # => 1
# or via convenient instance_variable_get method
puts a.instance_variable_get(:@x) # => 1
```

And now to instance variables inside `class_eval`:

```
# class_eval is instance method of Module class
# so it's not available for object a
# a.class_eval { } # => undefined method `class_eval' for #<A:0x8fbaa74>

# instance variable definition works the same inside
# class_eval and instance_eval
A.instance_eval { @y = 1 }
A.class_eval    { @z = 1 }

# both variables belong to A class itself
p A.instance_variables # => [:@y, :@z]

# instance variables can be accessed in both ways as well
puts A.instance_eval { @y } # => 1
puts A.class_eval    { @z } # => 1

# no instance_variables here
p A.new.instance_variables # => []
```

Now if you replace class `A` with class `Class` and object `a` with object `Klass` (that in this particular situation is nothing more than instance of class `Class`) I hope you'll get explanation to your questions. If you still have some feel free to ask.

Comment: Many thanks! Also, i think you should back from revision *huge write-up about classes* for other peoples!

Comment: I went too far from question =) Though, the most valuable parts of it in more structured form are present in this version, so I think it's ok.

Comment: Also, do you speak russian? Can i talk with you through gtalk?

Comment: @avy, yes, I speak Russian, but I'm not that interested in private consultancy =)

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to completely answer your question (for a thorough explanation of Ruby's class model, look at [Dave Thomas' excellent presentation](http://scotland-on-rails.s3.amazonaws.com/2A04_DaveThomas-SOR.mp4)), nevertheless:

With **class_eval**, you actually define instance methods - it's as if you were inside the body of the class. For example:

```
class Klass
end

Klass.class_eval do
  def instance_method
    puts 'instance method'
  end
end

obj = Klass.new
obj.instance_method  # instance method
```

With **instance_eval**, you actually define class methods - it's as if you were inside the body of the singleton (eigenclass) class of the given object (nota bene that classes are objects too in Ruby). For example:

```
Klass.instance_eval do
  def class_method
    puts 'class method'
  end
end

Klass.class_method  # class method
```

And in your case:

`Klass.instance_eval "@x"` does not work because `@x` is not part of Klass, it's part of Klass' singleton class:

```
class Klass
  class << self
    @x = "yeah"
  end

  puts @x
end

# prints nothing
```

`a.instance_eval "@x"` works fine because you evaluate "@x" in the context of the `a` singleton class that is connected with the singleton class of Klass class in which you defined the `@x` instance variable. How singleton classes can be interconnected can be illustrated by this example:

```
class Foo
end

f = class << Foo; self; end
g = class << Foo; self; end

f.instance_eval "def yeah; puts 'yeah'; end"

g.yeah  # yeah

g.instance_eval "def ghee; puts 'ghee'; end"

f.ghee  # ghee
```

`Klass.instance_eval "def yeah; puts 10; end"` defines a 'normal' class method. Therefore `Klass.yeah` works fine (see `Klass.class_method` in the previous example).

`a.instance_eval "def pops; puts 0; end"` defines a class method on the `a` singleton class. Therefore, `a.pops` actually means calling the `pops` class method (again, it's as if calling `Klass.class_method`).

`a.popsx` does not work because you would first have to create an instance of `a` to be able to call popsx on it (but is not possible to create a new instance of a singleton class).

`Klass.pops` does not work because there isn't any `pops` method defined in Klass' singleton class (`pops` is defined in `a`'s singleton class).

`Klass.popsx` works because with `a.class_eval "def popsx; puts 1; end"` you have defined the popsx instance method which you then call on the Klass object. It is, in a way, similar to this example:

```
class Other
end

o = Other.new

Other.class_eval "def yeah; puts 'yeah'; end"

o.yeah  # yeah
```

Hope it helps.